# Shortening JPA criteria query boilerplate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've used hibernate for a long time. Recently I started using JPA, but I can't find a short way to write a simple select in less than these seven lines (the use of criteria is a must in this project).

Is there a shorter way to build this query?

```
public List<Transaction> findDevolucionesByOriginalOperationId(String originalOperationId) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Transaction> cq = cb.createQuery(Transaction.class);
    Root<Transaction> root = cq.from(Transaction.class);
    Collection<Predicate>  predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("originalOperationId"), originalOperationId));

    cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    List<Transaction> resultado = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? Could you post some of the other functions as well? Perhaps one of the best answers would be to just let a function handle the boilerplate... But we don't know that without context =)

Comment: That's the entire DAO method, it's just a "select * from transaction where originalOperationid = X" there's no more than that.... but i feel that i resolved it in too many lines.

Comment: It took me a while to realize why the api is this unnatural. The basic reason as I understand it is that it is intended for the client to only refer to `javax.persistence` interfaces, nothing vendor-specific like Hibernate. This is great in theory but you can't build a query using a builder pattern because there are no static methods in interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

JPA Criteria API is horrific, even the creators admitted that it was designed for tooling support rather than for developers.
My personal favorite approach is to use a fluent query API like [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration).

The query in QueryDSL would look more or less as follows:

```
new JPAQuery().from(transaction)
    .where(transaction.originalOperationId.eq(originalOperationId))
   .list();
```

The difference is staggering. And the query is fully typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make a select in a shorter way! You should check at the [JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

You have at least four ways:

- Annotation based named query
- Query method declaration
- Query method using @Query
- Native query at the query method using @Query *

(*) Would not use this one.

Comment: You could elaborate a little more on the approaches you propose: How would they look? Can you link to or quote relevant documentation?

Comment: Everything you ask is in the link I add to the Jpa documentation.

Comment: At least one example would really be helpful rather than sifting through screens and screens that use terms that might be different in this context than the novice's.